# NLTK add custom negative and positive words

Tags: nlp, nltk, corpus, textblob

I am sentiment analysing comments with TextBlob (which uses NLTK).
However, I want to add custom negative and positive words but I can't find a location of a positive-word and negative-word location locally.

I am running iPython trough Anaconda.

Can someone tell me the location of the negative and positive words, or if this is even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's using an XML polarity lexicon, see [here](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/en/en-sentiment.xml). You should find the same folder structure you see on the Github replicated on your local install, or search for *en-sentiment.xml* .

Within the code, in the implementation of the `text` [class](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/_text.py), you can find more details on the dictionary's structure and how to adapt it:

> Each word in the lexicon has scores for:
>
> 1)     polarity: negative vs. positive    (-1.0 => +1.0)
>
> 2) subjectivity: objective vs. subjective (+0.0 => +1.0)
>
> 3)    intensity: modifies next word?      (x0.5 => x2.0)

Right below in the code, you will find the `Sentiment` class, where you could just point the `self._path` variable to any other XML file you want to use.

Thus

- locate lexicon and adapt
- change settings in code, e.g. Sentiment object

are two paths you could follow.

I have actually never used this package, so I have no more practical suggestions for you.